# iOS bluetooth Questions

Tags: ios, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to use my iPad to connect with a OLS426 Bluetooth low energy module to send data thorough the serial port on the Bluetooth module. I have successfully connected to the Bluetooth module. In the connection, the iPad is working as a central and the Bluetooth module as a peripheral.

Here are my questions:

(1)

```
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

I subscribe to the Bluetooth module in didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService.

```
    - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{

        NSLog(@"Subscribed");
```

}

After subscribing, the "Subscribed" log is printed on the terminal. Does it mean that I have successfully subscribed to the device?

(2)

I also try to write value for a characteristic in the didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService.

```
    [peripheral writeValue: data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Since I have set the type to be CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse, I think that if the writing is not successful, there will be an error. However, there is no error.

```
    - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
        NSLog(@"Hello sent");
    }
```

My question is why the "Hello sent" is not printed after I set a value for a characteristic?

(3)

I want to send some data thorough the serial port on the bluetooth module. I can only read data from a characteristic, like a heart rate monitor, or write data to a characteristic. In the services of the Bluetooth module, I find one called the "Serial Port" under which there is a characteristic called "FIFO". So I guess that I should write data to that characteristic in order to send data thorough the serial port. Can anyone tell me if my thinking is correct?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes.

2) `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` is called when the characteristic value changes independently of your own write to that characteristic.

3) Have you read the [connectBlue document](http://support.connectblue.com/display/PRODBTSPA/connectBlue+Low+Energy+Serial+Port+Service#connectBlueLowEnergySerialPortService-SerialPortConnection) on how to read/write data via the FIFO characteristic?

Comment: It says "The FIFO characteristic represents the data to be sent to the external interface, e.g. UART. All data that is received on this characteristic should be placed in an internal FIFO or directly put on the external interface.

When data is received on the external interface the data should be put in the internal FIFO." 

I tried to run a serial port listener on my laptop and connect the serial port of Bluetooth module on my laptop to listen data coming in. However, when I write a value to the FIFO characteristic, nothing is received on my laptop.

Comment: Did you use a level shifter?  It is very likely that the module will be operating at TTL levels, not RS-232 levels

Comment: No, I haven't...Is there anyway for me to check for the data output visibly?

Comment: You could probably attach an LED between TX and GND or connect TX to RX and then your data will be looped back to you